# Fire event on Word-Wrap

Tags: c#, winforms, text, richtextbox, word-wrap

Is there some way to find out **when** the text gets wrapped (WordWrap) inside a RichTextBox? I've dug around quite a bit but haven't found anything so far, will keep looking though...

The reason I'm looking into this is because I need an event to fire whenever the RichTextBox wraps the text at the end of the line.

Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically I believe this *is* possible with the Windows API. Take a look at [EM_SETHYPHENATEINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774242(v=VS.85).aspx) and in particular, the ability to pass a custom HyphenateProc. This is a pointer to a function that is called when the rich text box needs to wrap a line and calls your function to determine how to hyphenate the word.

Having said that, I sincerely doubt this is exposed in .NET so you would need to dig into the API a bit more. But I think this would be the best way of being notified on each line wrap.

**UPDATE**
Here you go I [found a blog post](http://hirerussians.wordpress.com/2008/11/25/richtextbox-in-net-20-and-word-wrap/) that talks about this in a bit more detail.